# Append the results from input fields from one page and show them on another page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do the following: 
- I have 2 pages (page 1 with input fields & page 2 where the entered input should display) 
- I need to get all that was typed from the first input field, and put the results inside the tag "content" of the 2nd page.

1º Page Input :

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page 1 - Input</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>
    <script>
        function submit() {

            var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val(); //Input Code HTML
            $("#iframeId").contents().find("body").html($("<div class='content'></div>").append(code));

        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Input</h2>
    <textarea name="message" id="input" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit();" />

    <iframe id="iframeId" name="iframeId" src="layout.html"></iframe>
    <div id="test">
        Text
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

2º Page Layout :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page 2 - Layout</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js'></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="foot"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

THANKS!

Comment: I am using iframe to display the layout and code in a single page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if both files are having the same origin:

```
<script>
    function submit() {
        var code = $('textarea[name=message]').val(); //Input Code HTML
        $('#iframeId').contents().find('.content').text(code);
    }
</script>
```

You were almost there :)

Comment: The HTML code you entered is being passed to page 2, but he's not getting in html but text. :(

Comment: Well, the input that you get from jQuery is just text. What would you like there to be instead?

Comment: Thanks for the help was only change. text (code) to html (code). :D

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:**

To insert on submit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#iframeId').load(function(){
        $('input[type="button"]').on('click',function(){
            $('#iframeId').contents().find('.content').html($('textarea[name=message]').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

To insert on type:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#iframeId').load(function(){
    $('textarea[name=message]').on('input',function(){
        $('#iframeId').contents().find('.content').html($(this).val());
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I could not place what was typed in the input layout.html

Comment: You mean, you dont want it to happen when type? you want it when submit?